# Amazon Rekognition error when trying to access S3 file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

This is the error that I see when trying to run text detection on an image from my s3 bucket: `botocore.errorfactory.InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the DetectText operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.`

bucket -> name of the bucket
name -> name of the file (ex: 123.jpg)

MY CODE (python):

```
client=boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='us-east-1')
    print('works till here')
    response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket': bucket,'Name': name}})
    print('works till here 2')
                        
    textDetections=response['TextDetections']
    print ('Detected text\n----------')
    for text in textDetections:
            print ('Detected text:' + text['DetectedText'])
            print ('Confidence: ' + "{:.2f}".format(text['Confidence']) + "%")
            print ('Id: {}'.format(text['Id']))
            if 'ParentId' in text:
                print ('Parent Id: {}'.format(text['ParentId']))
            print ('Type:' + text['Type'])
            print()
    return len(textDetections)

S3 bucket is on global and rekogntion is on us-east-1
```

Comment: Is the Amazon S3 bucket also in `us-east-1`? (Please note that buckets are not global -- they are in a specific region.) Try it with a bucket in the same region.

Comment: Hi! Yes, it is in us-east-1 as well

Answer (score 0):

I took your code, modified it to reference to my bucket and object, and imported boto3.

It gave exactly **the same error** that you received. I then realised that my bucket is in the Sydney region, so I removed the `region_name` parameter, so it would use my default region (Sydney).

I then ran it again and **it worked just fine**.

As an experiment, I then changed the `Name` to point to a non-existent object. It gave the error message again.

Therefore, your problem is likely to be either that the bucket is *not* in `us-east-1`, or an incorrect bucket name or key has been provided.